# How to click on component behind the modal in react-native?

Tags: typescript, react-native, onclick, modal-dialog, behind

How to click on component behind the modal in react native? I am using native modal.Is there any prop for that?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you show us the code you're using right now? That would clarify what component you're trying to click, and the layout of the page :)

Answer (score -2):

you have to use one of these two approaches:

1. Customise the RNModal library to have the access to the background page
2. Write you own modal to have the full accessibility on every element on pages